# Cannot figure out a way to mock JS object

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have built the following Graphql schema but I cannot figure out how to build the JS object for some fake data. Can someone help me figure what I am doing wrong?

```
// GraphQL schema
const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    apps: [App]
  }
  type App {
    id: ID!
    show: Show
    name: String
    url: String
    author: String
    price: Float
    image: String
  }
  type Show {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    airDate: String
    users: [User]
  }
  type User {
    id: ID
    name: String
    email: String
  }
`);
```

Here is what I mocked but it does not work

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      id: 1,
      show: 1,
      name: 'App 1',
      url: 'http://google.com',
      author: 'John',
      price: '0.00',
      image: 'http://img.vibethemes.com/VeryVibe-125x125.png'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      show: 1,
      name: 'App 2',
      url: 'http://yahoo.com',
      author: 'Bob',
      price: '2.99',
      image: 'http://img.vibethemes.com/VeryVibe-125x125.png'
    }
  ],
  shows: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'This is a cool show'
    }
  ]
}
```

But this gives me an error. I think maybe I have a wrong property name somewhere. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your `show` field in your schema's `App` type is directly referencing another type — i.e., the `Show` type; however, your JS mock data contains only an `id` reference to the show object.

You've really got two options here (if you're absolutely wedded to this schema and JS data):

1. Leave your schema unchanged, but change your JS data to follow your schema def like this, perhaps:

   ```
   module.exports = {
       apps: [
         {
            id: 1,
            show: {
                id: 1,
                name: 'This is a cool show'
            },
            name: 'App 1',
            url: 'http://google.com',
            author: 'John',
            price: '0.00',
            image: 'http://img.vibethemes.com/VeryVibe-125x125.png'
         }, // etc. etc.
   ```

Since you're directly referencing an object in your schema via `show: Show` you need to actually provide your schema with the appropriately nested data structure. It should be noted that with this particular data structure (depending on your implementation) you may need to add a simple field-level resolver to `App.show` to appropriately return the nested `Show` data.

2. If you don't need to access information about the `Show` object and only need an `id` to reference for future querying, you could change your schema to instead require a simple `ID` as the type resolution for `App.show`:

   ```
   type App {
       ...
       show: ID,
       ...
   }
   ```

There are cases where it makes sense to be able to dig down into nested data, but if you don't really need to do it don't give yourself the extra work.

All in all, hope this helps a bit.

Comment: So if I went with option 2 how would I do that if I am using `buildSchema`? I think option 1 would require a lot of duplication of data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [easygraphql](https://easygraphql.com/) to solve this challenge!! There are multiple packages that can be used:

1. [easygraphql-mock](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-mock/overview): if you want to return a complete mock of the type, you can use this package, and with this, you don't have to create fixtures for each type.
2. [easygraphql-tester](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-tester/overview): It's similar to [easygraphql-mock](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-mock/overview) but with the difference that you can return the mock of the query, check the [docs](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-tester/usage#mocking-queries-and-mutations)